Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference in ABINIT calculation
I am a beginner in using the Abinit software. For several weeks, I have been trying to perform calculations with a specified number of k-points (Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference).The error wasn't related to the input file, so I uninstalled all the libraries and Abinit as well (I used the package manager apt) and cleaned up. Currently, I am trying to redo the installation by manually building the libraries, but I have a persistent error with fftw3 when configuring my .ac9 file (configure: error: invalid FFTW3 configuration).
#Details of 'config.log' from the Abinit build
...
include <fftw3.h>
|
| #ifdef FC_DUMMY_MAIN
| #ifndef FC_DUMMY_MAIN_EQ_F77
| #  ifdef __cplusplus
|      extern "C"
| #  endif
|    int FC_DUMMY_MAIN() { return 1; }
| #endif
| #endif
| int
| main ()



{




fftw_plan *plan;



|       fftw_complex *a1, *a2;
|       fftw_execute_dft(*plan, a1, a2);
|
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:40966: result: no
configure:41103: error: in `/home/ubutu/abinit/build':
configure:41105: error: invalid FFTW3 configuration
...
#My configure file
Install prefix for the FFT library
with_fft="/home/ubutu/local"
with_fft_flavor="fftw3"
FFT_CPPFLAGS="-I/home/ubutu/local/include"
FFT_CFLAGS="-I/home/ubutu/local/include"
FFT_FCFLAGS="-I/home/ubutu/local/include"
FFT_LIBS="-L/home/ubutu/local/lib -lfftw3f -lfftw3"
Install prefix for the FFTW3 library
with_fftw3="/home/ubutu/local"
FFTW3_CPPFLAGS="-I/home/ubutu/local/include"
FFTW3_CFLAGS="-I/home/ubutu/local/include"
FFTW3_FCFLAGS="-I/home/ubutu/local/include"
FFTW3_LIBS=FFTW3_LIBS="-L/home/ubutu/local/lib -lfftw3f -lfftw3"
#FFTW code soure :fftw-3.3.10
Compilation steps:
./configure --prefix=$HOME/local --enable-single
make -j2
make check && make install
./configure --prefix=$HOME/local
make -j2
make check && make install
#My Fortran version
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Thank you for your help.

Welcome to the forum! Those messages aren't really helpful. Consider posting your input file and also post any relevant info preceding the crash in the log and *.abo files and post what is in ABI_MPIABORT file if it exists. Also note that this could be an issue with your build. Try recompiling with different libraries etc.

Thanks for your help, because of it, I had to review the entire installation but there is another issue that is blocking me!
